# Fluent Nhibernate list of entities serialization error

Tags: serialization, error-handling, fluent-nhibernate, entity

I'm trying to save some entities of fluent nhibernate in viewstate of asp.net page.\
Entity class is already marker with [Serializable] attribute, but still I get error on page:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

Is this error caused by proxy classes of nhibernate?
Any ideas? Thanks.

PS: Added some code

```
[Serializable]
public class ExcludedGroup : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsMatch { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CalculatedField { get; set; }
}

public ExcludedGroupMap()
{
    Table("Groups");

    Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.IsMatch);
    Map(x => x.CalculatedField).Not.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in base entity class. All hierarchy of classes should be marked with serializable attribute.